Is it possible to apply an AudioEffect to an AudioTrack that is MODE_STATIC?
Is it possible to apply an AudioEffect to an AudioTrack that is MODE_STATIC? I have tried several ways and the effect (PresetReverb) is simply ignored. ChatGPT and Gemini reported that it was not possible using MODE_STATIC, only MODE_STREAM, is this correct? I cannot find this limitation in the documentation.
I tried creating the PresetReverb with sessionId = 0, and then associating it with the audioTrack in question, but it didn't work (the code didn't return any errors, all callbacks have the code SUCCESS)

The mode only affects how samples are written, not the effects. How do you configure the effect? Do you have the Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS?
